# How make sessions in Django without username/password system?

Tags: python, django, session-cookies

I`m building Django app that should work in local net, the app should allow people to vote for some topics but only one vote per person. How can I control that without logging in with username/password?

I think that it should be something about cookies but I'm not sure is there some tools inbuilt in Django.

Comment: you can check by their local ip addresses

Comment: Note that what you are asking is impossible to do securely without some sort of identity/access control (e.g. username/password that you specifically ruled out). If you store info about user having voted in their session/cookie, the user can simply delete the cookie and vote again.

Answer (score 0):

From the Django docs:

**Using sessions in views**
When SessionMiddleware is activated, each HttpRequest object – the first argument to any Django view function – will have a session attribute, which is a dictionary-like object.

You can read it and write to request.session at any point in your view. You can edit it multiple times. E.g

```
request.session['has_voted'] = False

def vote(request, new_vote):
    if request.session.get('has_voted', False):
        return HttpResponse("You've already voted.")
    c = votes.Vote(vote=new_vote)
    c.save()
    request.session['has_voted'] = True
    return HttpResponse('Thanks for your vote!')
```